# LSTM in Python generating flat forecasts

Tags: python, keras, time-series, lstm

[image][image]I have daily data from July 2017-Dec 2018 which is non stationary in nature & I am trying to generate forecasts for the next six months i.e.; from Jan 2019- Jul 2019. I tried using SARIMAX & LSTM but I am getting flat forecasts. This is the first time I am using LSTM so I tried both RELU & Sigmoid as activation functions but the forecasts are flat

```
SARIMA
SARIMAX
LSTM
```

Following is a month's data:

```
           values
X_Date  
2017-07-01  15006.17
2017-07-02  15125.35
2017-07-03  13553.20
2017-07-04  14090.07
2017-07-05  14341.84
2017-07-06  15037.23
2017-07-07  15588.56
2017-07-08  16592.55
2017-07-09  16851.91
2017-07-10  15630.53
2017-07-11  15501.26
2017-07-12  15852.34
2017-07-13  15020.60
2017-07-14  17115.26
2017-07-15  17668.73
2017-07-16  17604.95
2017-07-17  16686.89
2017-07-18  16523.80
2017-07-19  17642.11
2017-07-20  17803.65
2017-07-21  18756.53
2017-07-22  19220.46
2017-07-23  18876.94
2017-07-24  18103.97
2017-07-25  18034.74
2017-07-26  16650.10
2017-07-27  17247.02
2017-07-28  17620.62
2017-07-29  18210.39
2017-07-30  17015.64
```

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
train = daily_data.iloc[:365]
test = daily_data.iloc[365:]

scaler.fit(train)


scaled_train = scaler.transform(train)
scaled_test = scaler.transform(test)

from keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator

scaled_train
# define generator
n_input = 7
n_features = 1
generator = TimeseriesGenerator(scaled_train, scaled_train,    
length=n_input, batch_size=1)


from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM


# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(200, activation='sigmoid', input_shape=(n_input,     
n_features)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

model.summary()

# fit model
model.fit_generator(generator,epochs=25)

model.history.history.keys()

loss_per_epoch = model.history.history['loss']
plt.plot(range(len(loss_per_epoch)),loss_per_epoch)

first_eval_batch = scaled_train[-7:]
first_eval_batch = first_eval_batch.reshape((1,n_input,n_features))

model.predict(first_eval_batch)

test_predictions = []

first_eval_batch = scaled_train[-n_input:]
current_batch = first_eval_batch.reshape((1, n_input, n_features))


np.append(current_batch[:,1:,:],[[[99]]],axis=1)



test_predictions = []

first_eval_batch = scaled_train[-n_input:]
current_batch = first_eval_batch.reshape((1, n_input, n_features))

for i in range(len(test)):

 # get prediction 1 time stamp ahead ([0] is for grabbing just the  
 number instead of [array])
 current_pred = model.predict(current_batch)[0]

 # store prediction
 test_predictions.append(current_pred) 

 # update batch to now include prediction and drop first value
 current_batch = np.append(current_batch[:,1:,:],                        

 [[current_pred]],axis=1)
```

The forecasts are a flat line.

Answer (score 1):

This is an older thread but I had a similar issue and it actually just turned out to be underfitting. Obviously there could be many reasons for this, but OP has 25 epochs in his script which is usually not enough. I was running 30 epochs and getting this straight line prediction when I unscaled the data (My computer isn't the best so I thought I could get away with fewer epochs):

[image: Underfit Prediction]

After upping the epochs, I got much better test and train results. There are plenty of other reasons why the predictions would come out like like straight lines but hopefully raising the epochs can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Try to set 'relu' as activation function in the first layer. [Here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-lstm-models-for-time-series-forecasting/) is a link to a great blog. It contains a lot of very useful details, especially if you start with machine learning.

Here are influence of number of epochs on result with my old model.
[5000 epochs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vquee.png)
[25 epochs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYZyT.png)
I'm also a little bit concern about amount of training data you have. I trained my model on 18,000 of records to predict next 24 hours but my model analyses pretty complex system. I don't know what describe your data but you have to think about number of possible dependencies in your system and how good your training data can prepare your model for them.
I'm new at machine learning but what learnt is that the biggest part of model preparation is trial and error method. Especially at the beginning.
The blog form the beginning of my answer helped me a lot I recommend you read it.

I remember that in my case I used wrong activation functions almost everywhere.

[Here](https://medium.com/greyatom/what-is-underfitting-and-overfitting-in-machine-learning-and-how-to-deal-with-it-6803a989c76) is a post about under- and over-fitting .

Comment: How did you solve it? I started with relu but that did not help

Comment: Could you send a screen of your result plot?

Comment: Added both the daily & monthly forecast plots

Answer (score 0):

A few issues:

1. 18 months worth of daily data is probably not substantial for a neural network to build an accurate prediction of the future.
2. Your model only has 1 LSTM layer, add a second one to benefit from its "memory":

```
from keras.layers import Dropout

# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_input,n_features), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(.4))
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu', return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(.4))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

If you provide your data I can take a closer look. Have you tried experimenting with the `n_input` variable? This may have an impact on your model.

Comment: Many thanks so if I break the data @ daily level tehre are over 500 data points. What would be the best way to share the data?

Comment: Hi thanks everyone . I think I have been able to fix the issue I was encountering. The challenge that I am facing now is to make out of time forecast . Can some one help me out to make forecast for a month ahead. I have data until December 2018 I want to forecast until March 2019. Can someone help?